# Ubuntu server DMZ

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, nextcloud

I have recently tested to reach my nextcloud Ubuntu server from the outside. I have turned on the DMZ to my server on the router, but I can't reach the server.I don't reach anything when I write the external IP adress. Any suggestions how I could do? I don't reach anything when I write the external IP adress

Comment: Sounds like you need to post forward as well

Comment: I don't know how to do that...

Comment: You need to read the user manual of your router and find the section on Port Forwarding, particularly HTTP and HTTPS; port 80 and 443) .

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you're using DMZ on the router for your server. That should open all ports to that server unless the router has re-directed ports prior to DMZ.

First, I would check with the ISP and make sure they allow standard server ports (sometimes they block them).
Also, make sure your Ubuntu firewall is not running at least tell you figure out what the problem is.